# What happened to the weather-app in the panel?

Tags: unity, indicator

it was so easy to show the weather in the panel, without installing an app.

why won't that be possible anymore in 11.04?

Answer (score 21):

The weather feature of the time/date applet was removed (weather isn't related to time :), and the weather indicator is now a separate application: [indicator-weather](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/indicator-weather) [image: Install indicator-weather]

After you've installed it you can run it from the dash or [add it to your startup applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-to-start-applications-at-startup-automatically-in-11-04).

[image]

You could install this in Natty if you need it, or even file a bug report asking them to include it by default. If you do, you can add that link to your question (for the bug) so others who are interested can say it affects them.

Comment: "weather isn't related to time" Although this is true in absolute I think the use case of the time/weather app turns around the concept of location, which is definitely related to a given time AND a weather state. The previous panel was nice because it was showing both data, and configuration was done in the same place. Now you have to setup time and weather locations separately, with the risk of displaying time and weather for different locations...
Having them separate and living independently is confusing. Time and weather locations should at least be automatically synchronized so that they

Answer (score 2):

The weather-applet used in pre-11.04 requires the use of 'gnome-panel'. By default Ubuntu 11.04 uses the Unity desktop interface which does not use 'gnome-panel'.

A weather-indicator can be installed from the Ubuntu Software Centre. This has much (if not all) of the functionality the weather-applet provided.

Comment: thanx so much!!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind adding a PPA to your software sources list, I'd recommend Lorenzo Carbonell's [my-weather indicator](https://launchpad.net/my-weather-indicator). Instructions to install the package:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicato
```

Actually, if you *do* mind adding another PPA, you can just go ahead and get the .deb file from http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu/pool/main/m/my-weather-indicator/.

Source: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/10/install-weather-indicator-ubuntu-14-10

Answer (score 0):

As of 9-23-16, the "weather-app in the panel" is once again able to show the temperature of your chosen locations once you have OK'd the (automatic) software update. Thank you!!! I was surprised how much I missed it.